# Error : Incorrect server name in eclipse while trying to connect microstrategy server

Tags: eclipse, microstrategy

I am receiving the error

```
[com.microstrategy.webapi SEVERE] [06/27/2016 15:23:27:760] [0] [CDSSXMLAdmin.GetHostAddr] Incorrect server name. :  [java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLAdmin.getHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLAdmin.AddDSSXMLClusterNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLCluster.addClusterNodes(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLClusterNode.RefreshClusterMembership(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLAdmin.InitConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLServerSessionImpl.FindNodes(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLServerSessionImpl.CreateSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.webapi.CDSSXMLServerSessionImpl.CreateSessionEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.objects.WebIServerSessionImpl.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.objects.WebIServerSessionImpl.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.objects.WebIServerSessionImpl.createNewSessionID(Unknown Source)
    at com.microstrategy.web.objects.WebSessionInfoImpl.getSessionID(Unknown Source)
    at wof.main(wof.java:30)
```

when i try to connect with microstrategy using Eclipse.Can someone help me out in resoling this issue.

I have the same server name as in the microstrategy server. I have also pinged that server using my local machine and it works

Comment: I am facing the same issue. but after these errors, my code gets executed. strange.